# Getting Started with CacheMoney

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, cache-money

I recently installed [cache-money](http://github.com/nkallen/cache-money/tree/master).  After some difficulties getting memcached and cache-money set up, I thought I had it working.  It cached the one query on my login page fine.  I login, and go to my message index page and get this error:

```
indices delegated to @cache_config.indices, but @cache_config is nil: Slug(id: integer, name: string, sluggable_id: integer, sequence: integer, sluggable_type: string, scope: string, created_at: datetime)
```

Searching for the first part of that error message returns 0 hits on Google, so I'm at a loss on where to even begin.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have missed setting an index in your Message model. Cache Money will work automatically for fields like id, but otherwise you need to set them yourself.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  index [:subject, :body, :sender]
end
```

Comment: To clarify, what do I do with models that I don't want indexed?  Or is there a way to specify only certain files for caching?

Comment: "Indexed" in this context just means: field that I will be querying on. 

If you aren't going to query on a model, don't put in the index settings in it.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is I haven't indexed it...

I have is_cached :repository => $cache in my cache_money.rb file.  Do I need to move it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

2 weeks ago the friendly_id side recognized this issue and closed it to fix first by the cache-money side before playing with friendly_id:

http://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/closed#issue/33

So you have to do without one of the 2 plugins for the time being.